# Owner and group of an hdiutil attached disk image

Tags: disk-utility, permission, hdiutil

It's known that a disk image attached with ignored owners (`vsdbutil -c` prints disabled) will have owner and group to match whatever user is accessing the disk.

However, the following bit from diskutil's man says it may behave differently:

> The behavior is different when disk images are attached. With disk
> images, the owner of all files in a filesystem mount for which owners
> are ignored is the user attaching the disk image. The attaching owner
> is also used when creating new files.

I cannot replicate this. Despite the attaching user, owner and group are always set to match whomever is accessing disk's files.

Comment: What version of macOS? I get `No entry found for ...` when I do `sudo vsdbutil -c /Volumes/xxx` for an ignored owners disk image.  I also note that vdsbutil is "deprecated" and man page is unchanged for 21 years.

Comment: Big Sur (11.6.5). That's the only CLI way to check for this I know of, but you can also see whether Owners are enabled via Disk Utility -> Get Info. I guess you get the error because you have never changed the value for that setting and the utility only reads records from the database.